# GreenDroid PagedView - Multiple pages (different layout) help.. Android SDK

Tags: java, android, class, sdk

I've spent the day playing around with the GreenDroid PagedView and PagedAdaptor to create multiple screens that one can swipe through (a la iPhone style and Android Home Screen style).  It's a very cool effect and the GreenDroid library is awesome.  Soo.. I can get this working for one XML layout (code below), but what I am attempting to do is have three screens with different layouts. I've played around and got it working successfully with one method, but am unsure whether the method I'm using will cause problems due to repeat inflation of XML layout at every method call. I'll give some examples of what I've tried to save time.  I'm hoping someone reads this that has had experience with GreenDroid and can point me in the right direction.  Maybe this will also help someone else too..

Here is my code:

**HomePageActivity.java**

```
public class HomePageActivity extends GDActivity {

private static final int PAGE_COUNT = 3;

private final Handler mHandler = new Handler();
private PageIndicator mPageIndicator;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setActionBarContentView(R.layout.homepage_view);   // container xml

    final PagedView pagedView = (PagedView) findViewById(R.id.homepage_view);
    pagedView.setOnPageChangeListener(mOnPagedViewChangedListener);
    pagedView.setAdapter(new HomePageAdapter());

    mPageIndicator = (PageIndicator) findViewById(R.id.page_indicator);
    mPageIndicator.setDotCount(PAGE_COUNT);

    setActivePage(pagedView.getCurrentPage());        
}

private void setActivePage(int page) {
    mPageIndicator.setActiveDot(page);
}

private OnPagedViewChangeListener mOnPagedViewChangedListener = new OnPagedViewChangeListener() {

    @Override
    public void onStopTracking(PagedView pagedView) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onStartTracking(PagedView pagedView) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageChanged(PagedView pagedView, int previousPage, int newPage) {
        setActivePage(newPage);
    }
};

private class HomePageAdapter extends PagedAdapter {

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return PAGE_COUNT;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        if (convertView == null) {
            Log.i("getView","ConvertView is null");
                convertView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.homepage_one, parent, false);
        } 
        Log.i("getView Page",Integer.toString(position));

        return convertView;
    }

}
```

The two lines:

```
 Log.i("getView","ConvertView is null");
Log.i("getView Page",Integer.toString(position));
```

I am using to debug this to see what is happening via. LogCat and so I can experiment.
The first line is displayed ONCE - first time application is created.  I've noticed that VERY VERY occasionally as I swipe through the pages (I have three - set by variable PAGE_COUNT at top), that after 30-50 swipes I will see this message again.  This shows that this layout is only INFLATED once - for all screens.

The second line I naturally see every time I change page.  The integer position is either 0, 1 or 2 in this particular case.

The XML layout homepage_one is a simple layout with three TextViews.  The XML layout homepage_view is the container for these pages.

**homepage_view.xml**

```
<merge
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:greendroid="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.cyrilmottier.android.gdcatalog">

<greendroid.widget.PagedView
    android:id="@+id/homepage_view"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/splash" />

<greendroid.widget.PageIndicator
    android:id="@+id/page_indicator"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="top|center_horizontal"
    android:paddingTop="10dp" />
```

Naturally I've tried some obvious methods such as this:  (which works as wanted)

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        if (position == 0) {
                convertView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.homepage_one, parent, false);
        } else if( position == 1 ){
             convertView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.homepage_two, parent, false);
        } else {
             convertView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.homepage_three, parent, false);
        }
        return convertView;
}
```

This works as intended.  Every screen is different as I want.  I've not noticed any performance problems during testing, but it's worth noting in the original instance that we only inflate the layout ONCE.  As this method is called (which is every time the page changes, we inflate the layout again.  This doesn't seem resourceful, but then again this is my first week with Android development and I don't know how the architecture works... (just reading, reading, reading and testing, testing, testing) - so hence why I would like to hear from more experienced and knowledgeable developers.  This may well be acceptable.. I would like to hear from you.

I tried this:

```
 public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        if (PAGE_ONE == false && position == 0) {
                convertView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.homepage_one, parent, false);
             PAGE_ONE = true;
        } else if(PAGE_TWO == false && position == 1 ){
             convertView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.homepage_two, parent, false);
             PAGE_TWO = true;
        } else if( PAGE_THREE == false && position == 2 ){
             convertView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.homepage_three,parent, false);
                 PAGE_THREE = true;
        }
        return convertView;
}
```

PAGE_ONE, PAGE_TWO, PAGE_THREE were set in the class as private boolean = false.  The consideration behind this is that we only inflate layout once and every other call to this method simply returns the already inflated xml layout.  Unfortunately this crashes my emulator and my phone (HTC EVO 3D).  As Jay-Z would say, on to the next one...

Any ideas guys?

Answer (score 1):

The GreenDroid's `PagedView` is normally intended to display a large set of pages. It can be considered as an horizontal paged `ListView`. This is the reason why using it is very close to the common `ListAdapter`.

In your case, you want to keep three pages in memory. This is completely possible but not recommended as you are preventing the `PagedView` from recycling your pages and also increasing the amount of `View` in memory.

Having only 3 pages (with a relatively flat and narrow `View` hierarchy) is OK. A better way do to what you are trying to do would be to lazily-initialize the pages and keep a reference on each pages.

```
private static final int PAGE_COUNT = 3;

private View[] mPages = new View[PAGE_COUNT];

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    if (mPages[position] == null) {
        View page = createPageAtPosition(position, parent);
        mPages[position] = page;
    }

    return mPages[position];
}
```

Of course you may have a warning in your logs as the `PagedView` notify the developer when the convertView is not reused.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into a similar issue as well.  Not sure if it is a bug with GreenDroid or user error on my part.  (The latter is more likely)

Anyway, here is the solution I came up with.  Your solution was nearly there, but you missed the critical 'else' condition when grabbing an existing view.  It's working quite well for me.

```
/** get the view to display */
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
   pageEnum currentPage = pageEnum.values()[position];

   if(null == mViews[position]) {
      switch(currentPage) {
      case PAGE_1:
         convertView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.page1, parent, false);
         break;

      case PAGE_2L:
         convertView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.page2, parent, false);
         break;

      case PAGE_3:
         convertView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.page3, parent, false);
         break;

      default:
         convertView = null;
         Log.e(TAG, "Invalid page.");
         break;
      }   /* switch(currentPage) */

         mViews[position] = convertView;
   }   /* if(null == mViews[position]) */
   else {
      convertView = mViews[position];
   }

   return convertView;
}   /* getView() */
```